# создание авторизации через SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class personal extends Activity  {
    EditText password;
    EditText username;
    Button enterbtn;
    SharedPreferences mSharedPref;
    final String USERNAME = "Имя";
    final String PASSWORD = "Пароль";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.personal);

    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    enterbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterbtn);
}
    public void save(View view){


    mSharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPref.edit();
        mEditor.putString(USERNAME, username.getText().toString());
        mEditor.putString(PASSWORD, password.getText().toString());
        mEditor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Данные сохранены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    }
```

Создал в приложении логин и пароль, подскажите пожалуйста как возможно при первом запуске сохранить его в при дальнейших запусках приложения только сравнивать с введённым - то есть сделать проверку логина и пароля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я "на коленке" писал, возможны мелкие ошибки.. Суть такая.
Читаем из преференсов поле `isStart`  - при первом запуске оно будет отсутствовать  и по умолчанию  ему присвоится значение `false`.
По такому условию вызываем метод `enterAuth()` - ввод имени и пароля пользователя, сохранение их и тд., так же устанавливаем флаг `isStart` в `true` - при следующем заходе `isStart` уже будет в преференсах и будет установлен в `true` - будет вызван метод `compareAuth()` - сравнение данных с уже имеющимися.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.personal);

  ///

  mSharedPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
  boolean isStart = mSharedPref.getBoolean("isStart", false);
  if (isStart) {
     compareAuth();
     }
  else {
      Editor e = mSharedPref.edit();
      e.putBoolean("isStart", true);
      e.commit(); 
      enterAuth();
    }
  }
```

Для того, чтобы сбросить авторизацию, нужно будет установить `isStart` в преференсах назад в `false`.
Методы `enterAuth()` и `compareAuth()` - для примера, вы должны их реализовать самостоятельно, а назвать, как вам вздумается.

Хранить регистрационные данные в преференсах - плохая идея, там они никак не защищены\зашифрованы и любой желающий сможет получить к ним доступ при небольшом старании

Comment: а если добавить ещё hashed? или в чём лучше хранить регистрационные данные?

Comment: ну можно и в преференсах, но шифрануть как то надо все же . В Java есть целый класс `Security` для серьезных дел по скрытию инфы, а по простому тоже полно алгоритмов и решений.  Погуглите или новый вопрос создавайте, если самому не в моготу