# Как запустить разные Activity при первом и втором входе в Android-приложение?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Начинаю знакомиться с Android Studio.
Пытаюсь реализовать следущую штуку. При первом входе в приложение пользователю предлагается указать свой логин для дальнейшей работы. Данные записываются с помощью getPreferences

```
private void saveLogin() {
    sLogin = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sLogin.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, uName.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();
```

При повторном запуске приложения необходимо сделать так, чтобы открывался другой Activyty, поскольку пользователь уже вводил логин. Попытался в onCreate вызвать что-то такое:

```
if (uName != null){
        View vr = null;
        Intent intent = new Intent(vr.getContext(), Account.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        intent.putExtra("name", uName.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent)
```

Выдает ошибку.
Подскажите способ решения. Наверняка существует и более элегантный способ решения, о котором я не знаю. Спасибо.

Полный код класса:

```
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
Button login_button;
EditText uName;

//SharedPreferences login save
SharedPreferences sLogin;

final String SAVED_TEXT ="saved_text";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    /*if (uName != null){
        View vr = null;
        Intent intent = new Intent(vr.getContext(), Account.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        intent.putExtra("name", uName.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);

    }*/

    uName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uName);
    login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    loadText();
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Account.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    intent.putExtra("name", uName.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
            "Welcome to My Own Bookshelf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.login_button:
            saveLogin();
            break;
    }



}



//save login
private void saveLogin() {
    sLogin = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sLogin.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, uName.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();
}

private void loadText() {
    sLogin = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedText = sLogin.getString(SAVED_TEXT,"");
    uName.setText(savedText);
    //ONLY FOR CHECKING saveLogin METHOD
    /*Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Your logged in as " + sLogin.getString(SAVED_TEXT,""), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

}
```

}

Comment: сначала нужно получить из преференсов какое-то значение (признак регистрации), потом его сравнивать. С чего вы взяли, что в в вашем uName что то будет при старте активити, вы присвоили туда какое то значение?

Comment: активити сама наследник контекста, зачем получать его из какого то специально созданного View vr,  достаточно `this`. Данные сначала нужно положить в интент (`putExtra()`), потом вызывать новое активити, для чего первый (пустой) вызов ... Рекомендую вам читать литературу, а не какие то кусочки в интернете, чем вы, судя по всему (и вашим "нелепым" ошибкам), занимаетесь сейчас. Хорошая книга Б.Харди "Android для профессионалов" 2 издание, но похоже, что сначала еще потребуется улучшить знания по самой Java, Шилдта там почитать или Эккеля

Comment: Алгоритм определения, [нужна ли авторизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424612/177345) в зависимости от значения в SharedPreferences. Большая [статья с множеством нюансов](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) по авторизации через преференсы. Так же есть множество уже [готовых библиотек](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=android+login&type=) для авторизации

Comment: "С чего вы взяли, что в в вашем uName что то будет при старте активити, вы присвоили туда какое то значение?" Ну, в классе вызывается сохранение и загрузка значения в Preferences. Как обращатся непосредственно к нему информации пока не нашел. Но при втором старте поле с  ID uName ужe заполнено. С того и взял, а точнее предположил.

Comment: 2. Обязательно воспользуюсь Вашим советом по литературе, но так или иначе, время от времени что-то придется перескакивать, особенно когда знаний минимум, времени минимум, а перед тобой ставят конкретную задачу. Именно в такой ситуации я сейчас. Надо быстро сделать, долго пытался сам, не вышло, спросил практического совета.

Comment: И все таки, материалы, которые Вы сбросили, я так понимаю из просмотренного больше касаются дальнейшей _проверки данных авторизации_ . В моем же случае один раз вводится логин без пароля, а все последующие сразу стартует второе активити. Собственно с этом пока главный вопрос. _Как при втором запуске изменить стартовое активити?_

Comment: первая ссылка из третьего комментария

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего поставить флажок boolean
По умолчанию сетить туда значение false
При первом входе запрашивать значение и в зависимости от того, что приходит в ответ выбирать активность.
Написал вам метод, вставьте дополните его запусками нужных активностей и запустите в onCreate

```
private void checkFirstStart() {

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("hasVisited",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // проверяем, первый ли раз открывается программа (Если вход первый то вернет false)
    boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);

    if (!hasVisited) {
        // Сработает если Вход первый

        //Ставим метку что вход уже был
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
        e.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
        e.commit(); //После этого hasVisited будет уже true и будет означать, что вход уже был

        //Ниже запускаем активность которая нужна при первом входе

    }else {

        //Сработает если вход в приложение уже был
        //Ниже запускаем активность которая нужна при последующих входах
    }
}
```

Прочитайте вот эту статью, тут здорово написано http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php