# Показать активити блокировки единственный раз после того как пароль совпадает

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Помогите ребята не могу сделать чтобы Activity с секретным кодом показался лишь единственный раз если пароль правильный, иначе показывать этот Activity пока не будет забит правильный пароль. (Android Studio) Спасибо заранее

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424612/177345/ Вместо вызова методов вы можете вызывать нужные активити

Comment: я новичок и поэтому может объяснить по подробнее

Comment: Делаете активити с вводом пароля, когда пароль будет введен правильно, записываете в преференсы `true`. При старте этой активити делаете проверку на значение в преференсах и если там `true` ,то переходите сразу на другую активити.

Comment: Спасибо pavloff помогли

Comment: А еще лучше сделать на фрагментах, чтобы не было задержек на создание активити, которая возможно не нужна, то есть в активити по состоянию флага в преференсах определять, какой нужен экран и выводить соответствующий фрагмент.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  boolean isLogin = pref.getBoolean("isLogin", false);

  if (isLogin) {
     WorkFragment fragment = new WorkFragment();
  } else {
     PasswordFragment fragment = new PasswordFragment();
    }

  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container">

</FrameLayout>
```

в `PasswordFragment`, когда проверили, что пароль правильный выполняете следующий код:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
Editor e = pref.edit();
e.putBoolean("isLogin", true);
e.apply();
```

Здесь `PasswordFragment` - фрагмент ввода пароля, `WorkFragment` - фрагмент с работающей программой.