# Программная смена запускаемой активности

Tags: java, android, activity

Имеется две активности: активность аутентификации (далее акт. Auth) и главная активность приложения (далее акт. Main).

При запуске приложения открывается акт. Auth и идет проверка аутентификации, затем идет переключение на акт. Main.

Как сделать так, чтобы на авторизованных устройствах сразу запускалось акт. Main?

Comment: Все можно сделать проще. Запускать main активность и уже в ней проверять аутентиф. В зависимости от результата запускать или нет активность с auth.

Comment: @UjinUkr Спасибо, сначала не правильно понял как это правильно сделать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424612/177345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно дописать обработчик активности Auth - чтобы если пользователь авторизован, не учитывать активность Auth, а учитывать активность Main.

Comment: А как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Нужно больше данных.
Создай вопрос (или укажи в текущем) и напиши что за язык используешь, и как сейчас учитываются активности в обоих случаях (если код учета писал сам - его тоже укажи).